# Unable to find the module 'angular/common' in angular2 typescrtip

Tags: typescript, angular, npm, node-modules, angular2-forms

I am trying a sample login form in angular 2 but when i am importing 'Form_Directives' as

```
 import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
```

It shows the error angular/common module is not found.My included files are

```
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Am i missed any modules,please can someone help

Comment: `@angular/common` is Angular2 >= RC.0. the script tags in your question are from Angular2 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@angular/common` is Angular2 >= RC.0. the script tags in your question are from Angular2 beta.

This might work for you:

```
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
```

Comment: Hi gunter,it again shows error cannot find module 'angular2/common'

Comment: sorry hunter i made a mistake,its working nw thank you

Comment: What Angular2 version do you actually want to use?

Comment: how can i check my angular version

Comment: Not sure, I don't use TS myself (only Dart) and I don't know much about npm and stuff. `angular2` is definitely `<=beta`. `@angular/xxx` is `=>RC`. If you use https://github.com/angular/angular-cli it creates a project structure and config for the newest version. The system.js config contains the concrete version that you can adjust.